# In Chrome JS debugger, how do I print all the properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I have opened the Javascript Debugger (Ctrl+Shift+L) in Chrome and started using it to set breakpoints in my code.

This is a much different interface compared to Firebug, (it's all command line driven) so I'm wondering how to do a simple thing like print all the properties of an object.

If I have an object like this:

```
var opts = {
  prop1: "<some><string/></some>",
  prop2: 2,
  prop3: [1,2,3]
}
```

I can set a breakpoint and inspect the object, but I only seem to get a single property back, and I'm not sure which property will appear:

```
$ print opts
#<an Object>
```

Trying to get all the properties:

```
$ print for(var p in opts) p;
prop1
```

Any ideas?
It obviously has more than just one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've tried using the "dir" command, and it gives me something at least:

```
$dir opts 
3 properties  
prop1: string (#11#) 
prop2: string (#12#)  
prop3: string (#13#)
```

This also works (slightly better because it gives me some values), but cuts off the end of the string if it's too long:

```
$ print var s=[];for(var p in opts) { s.push(p + ":" + opts[p]); } s.join(",");
prop1:<some><string/></some>,prop2:2,prop3:[object Object]
```

Answer (score 6):

Chrome has ECMA-style native JSON, so you can use

```
JSON.stringify (opts);
{"prop1":"<some><string/></some>","prop2":2,"prop3":[1,2,3]}
```

Comment: This is good to know, but it seems like it doesn't work in the debugger. (ReferenceError: JSON is not defined)

Answer (score 1):

You can just type the object name into the Chrome debugger command line and get a browsable listing.  In my case I wanted all the properties and methods that I could cut/paste to an external document.  This worked for me:

```
for (a in opts) console.log(typeof (opts[a]) + ' :: ' + a);
```

returns:

```
string :: id
string :: name
number :: selectMode
string :: url
boolean :: multi
object :: selectedRows
object :: selectedValues
function :: Load
function :: _LoadInternal
function :: _CreatePostElements
...etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command line in the JavaScript console at the bottom of the Inspector (`Ctrl+Shift+J`). It has a much more Firebug-like feel to it.

Comment: How do I set a breakpoint using the Inspector?  My problem is that I want to pause execution and inspect the value of the object.